# Calling a route from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to call a particular route from a rake task how will I achieve this.
 Example- I have a route /order/:id/show. I want to call that route from a rake task and I also want to pass :id in that process so that according function in the controller gets called. Is it possible in rails?

Comment: Why do you want to call your app from a rake task? What do you try to achieve? Did you concider to use `rails runner` and call Rails methods directly?

Comment: I am trying to make changes to an already existing application.so i want to call a route and pass parameters to that route so that desired function gets called. if this is not possible can you tell me how to call function in a controller from rake task by passing parameters(as post) to it. In other words I want to accomplish same thing as how we call route from a view file, but fro a rake task

Comment: Thanks peterh for your advise. Will definitely work on this.